# How do you show stacks on Highchart legend rather than series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm making a chart of attendance data for a project I'm working on. The data is grouped by week with a stacked column for each event. The columns are stacked by people-group (Adults, Children).

As this graph will be populated by user generated data, with no upper limit on number of people-groups, I've opted to keep the colours the same for all stacks within a column rather than generate a new colour for each new stack.

I want to be able to have the legend display the stack names [Sunday 10.30am, Sunday 6pm etc] with the associated colour, rather than the series names [Adults, Children].

Is this possible, and can it be done in such a way that hovering over each stack in the legend highlights the whole column?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alystarr/pen/abJNPaK)

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Attendance This Month'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['04-Apr-2021', '11-Apr-2021', '18-Apr-2021', '25-Apr-2021', '02-May-2021']
  },

  yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Attendance'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
      var stackName = this.series.userOptions.stack;
      return '<b>' + stackName + '</b><br/>' +
        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  colors: ['#e64980', '#e64980', '#be4bdb', '#be4bdb', '#18AABF', '#18AABF'],
  series: [{
    name: 'Adults',
    data: [103, 110, 107, 100, 100],
    stack: 'Sunday 10.30am'
  }, {
    name: 'Children',
    data: [41, 50, 49, 32, 100],
    stack: 'Sunday 10.30am'
  },{
    name: 'Adults',
    data: [100, 108, 105, 96, 75],
    stack: 'Sunday 6pm'
  }, {
    name: 'Children',
    data: [20, 31, 29, 3, 50],
    stack: 'Sunday 6pm'
  },{
    name: 'Adults',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    stack: 'Wednesday 12pm'
  }, {
    name: 'Children',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 25],
    stack: 'Wednesday 12pm'
  }]
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So basically you would like to create a custom legend for each stacked column separately?